# How to use Amazon Cognito with my own identity provider?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I would like to use Amazon Cognito with my own identity provider like this:

[image]

How can I do that? (I'm working on an Amplify project).

I find this documentation but it's not helpful:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js/

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is [Identity Federation via Cognito user pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-federation.html#cognito-user-pools-identity-federation-how-it-works).

In order to do that, your Identity Provider should support *OpenId Connect (OIDC)* or *SAML*. Then you can configure your IDP in Cognito either using [OIDC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-oidc-idp.html) or using [SAML](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-saml-idp.html).

Then in your application you can use [`Auth.federatedSignIn()`](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js/#setup-frontend) along with the provider that you have configured.

Something similar is discussed in [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-an-application-with-aws-amplify-amazon-cognito-and-an-openid-connect-identity-provider/) blog post as well.